An analogue of the de Rham complex for vector fields
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\chi$ be its tangent bundle and $\Omega^1$ be its bundle of $1$-forms. Using the exterior algebra we can extend the space of sections of $\Omega^1$ to a differential graded algebra called the de Rham complex. Is there an analogous construction for vector fields - i.e. sections of $\chi$. Is there some way to extend them to a (co)chain complex?

Yes, but as far as I am aware you need additional structure on your manifold. Let $\mathfrak{X}^{\bullet}(M)$ be the graded vector space of multivector fields. Given a nondegenerate bilinear form $B$ on each tangent space, that is, a smooth section of the second tensor power of the cotangent bundle (e.g. a Riemannian metric, a symplectic form), one has the induced "musical isomorphisms" $\flat:TM\rightarrow T^*M$ and $\sharp:T^*M\rightarrow TM$, taking a tangent vector $v$ to the functional $B(-,v)$, and the inverse of this map. The bundle isomorphism $\sharp$ gives a graded isomorphism $\Omega^{\bullet}(M)\rightarrow \mathfrak{X}^{\bullet}(M)$, and there is a unique differential on $\mathfrak{X}^{\bullet}(M)$ so that this isomorphism is a chain map, and the cohomology of our complex is canonically isomorphic to de Rham cohomology.
For Riemannian manifolds, the 0th differential is the gradient, and 1st is bivector curl.
If one has a Poisson structure on the manifold, then one can also make $\mathfrak{X}^{\bullet}(M)$ into a cochain complex with differential $[\pi,-]$, where $\pi$ is the Poisson bivector and $[-,-]$ is the Schouten bracket (I think there is some ambiguity here in the choice of sign). If the Poisson manifold is symplectic, then we recover the above. The cohomology of this complex is called Poisson cohomology.
